# Edit gamefile/console database manually retroarch

Tags: bash, scripts, games

retroarch is a great frontend, but what it lacks is some of the settings other console emulators have to make the game look 10x better.

I have added a core that can execute bash/shell scripts from retroarch and it works beautifully, however the box art will not download for the scripts I have made.

Is there a way that I can manually add the information to list a bash script as a psp game, ps1 game etc? And where I can locate the directory to edit some of the menus etc? Thanks. :)

Just need to find a way to add the box art

Comment: Please move answer part to the answer field below.

Comment: apologies, I don't really use the forums unless I have to so I don't post near as much and still unfamilar with some of the guidelines, this is good to know, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the playlist and can manually edit them in `/home/USER/.config/retroarch/playlists` .

All my research is done and have managed to get it working successfully, will help answer what questions i can to get this solved for others.